# with this.location.back() only url is getting changed ,it's not loading the correct tab

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

```
 back() 
  {
    this.location.back();
  }
```

while loading the tab, changing the URL for that  particular tab manually:

```
  this.router.navigate([this.routerUrl], {queryParams:{q:'apps'} })
```

this.router.navigate is not registering the URL in history, since on press of back button only URL getting changed but it's not loading the correct tab inside parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in appComponent...

Working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b1paej?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

```
this.location.back();
```